# vs2022 with azure git When I rebuild, it creates or changes some files by itself

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGKwc.png)

When I rebuild, it creates or changes some files by itself.

I push these files after commit.

When I rebuild it again, it's the same.

I think i am doing something wrong.

I was using tfs. I'm migrating to git.
You can see the details of my project in the picture above.

Comment: Sounds you included _products of the build_ in the commits (which should not be done).

Comment: how can i remove

Comment: If it is a small project and assuming you are just learning and no one will come back to complain, run `git rm --cached <the-files>`, then add them to `.gitignore` so that git does not pay attention to them anymore and do not get added again. Now, if the project is _for real_ (you want to publish it and stuff), you should consider rewriting history to remove them from the history of the project... there are already many questions like that with many many good answers on how to do that.